# Python: Draw line between two coordinates in a matrix

Tags: python

I have a matrix of size `N x N` defined as `M = np.zeros((N,N))` and two coordinates `[x0,y0]` and `[x1,y1]`. Now I want to connect these two points with ones.

An example for `N=5` would be:

Lets set the coordinates to `2` in the matrix

```
[x0,y0] = [0,3]
[x1,y1] = [4,2]
```

Then the matrix should look something like:

```
M = 
    0 0 0 2 0
    0 0 0 1 0
    0 0 1 0 0
    0 0 1 0 0
    0 0 2 0 0
```

What would be a simple approach to do that?

Comment: Interesting. One guessproach: Iterate over all coordinates. If the distance between the line and the coordinate is less than 0.5, that coordinate should be on the line. try it.

Comment: This is the same problem as choosing two pixels on a screen and deciding which pixels in between should be lit up to connect them in a straight line. Check out [line drawing algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_drawing_algorithm) and other similar tutorials for how this has already been solved.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Wow, exactly what I am looking for.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice True, although I think the problem of implementing this efficiently with NumPy may still be interesting.

Comment: @jdehesa Good point. I can't speak to a numpy implementation since I am only a beginner with that libarary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is one simple implementation with NumPy, just computing the line equation:

```
import numpy as np

def draw_line(mat, x0, y0, x1, y1, inplace=False):
    if not (0 <= x0 < mat.shape[0] and 0 <= x1 < mat.shape[0] and
            0 <= y0 < mat.shape[1] and 0 <= y1 < mat.shape[1]):
        raise ValueError('Invalid coordinates.')
    if not inplace:
        mat = mat.copy()
    if (x0, y0) == (x1, y1):
        mat[x0, y0] = 2
        return mat if not inplace else None
    # Swap axes if Y slope is smaller than X slope
    transpose = abs(x1 - x0) < abs(y1 - y0)
    if transpose:
        mat = mat.T
        x0, y0, x1, y1 = y0, x0, y1, x1
    # Swap line direction to go left-to-right if necessary
    if x0 > x1:
        x0, y0, x1, y1 = x1, y1, x0, y0
    # Write line ends
    mat[x0, y0] = 2
    mat[x1, y1] = 2
    # Compute intermediate coordinates using line equation
    x = np.arange(x0 + 1, x1)
    y = np.round(((y1 - y0) / (x1 - x0)) * (x - x0) + y0).astype(x.dtype)
    # Write intermediate coordinates
    mat[x, y] = 1
    if not inplace:
        return mat if not transpose else mat.T
```

Some tests:

```
print(draw_line(np.zeros((5, 5)), 0, 3, 4, 2))
#[[0. 0. 0. 2. 0.]
# [0. 0. 0. 1. 0.]
# [0. 0. 1. 0. 0.]
# [0. 0. 1. 0. 0.]
# [0. 0. 2. 0. 0.]]
print(draw_line(np.zeros((5, 5)), 4, 2, 0, 3))
#[[0. 0. 0. 2. 0.]
# [0. 0. 0. 1. 0.]
# [0. 0. 1. 0. 0.]
# [0. 0. 1. 0. 0.]
# [0. 0. 2. 0. 0.]]
print(draw_line(np.zeros((5, 5)), 1, 0, 3, 4))
#[[0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
# [2. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
# [0. 1. 1. 1. 0.]
# [0. 0. 0. 0. 2.]
# [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
```

Comment: Great! Works like a charm. But whats the `inplace` for?

Comment: @Samuel Ah yeah not very important I just tend to put it on NumPy functions... With `inplace=True` you'd modify the passed array instead of creating a new one.

Answer (score 2):

If you treat the array conceptually as a matrix of pixels, then you can use [Bresenhams line drawing algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham's_line_algorithm) to draw a line between these two points.

Answer (score 2):

This is the same problem as choosing two pixels on a screen and deciding which pixels in between should be lit up to connect them in a straight line. Check out [line drawing algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_drawing_algorithm) and other similar tutorials for how this has already been solved.

Answer (score 2):

Consider DDA Line Generation Algorithm. It is used to plot points in a line between two points. Here, instead of a drawing canvas, you have to fill places in an array.

Here's my take to it:

```
def printarr():
    for row in board:
        print ' '.join([str(x) for x in row]) 

def makeline():
    dx = point2[0] - point1[0]
    dy = point2[1] - point1[1]
    steps = dx if (dx>dy) else dy
    xinc= dx/float(steps)
    yinc = dy/float(steps)

    x = point1[0]
    y = point1[1]
    for i in range(steps+1):
        if (board[abs(x),abs(y)] == 0):
            board[abs(x),abs(y)]=1
        x+=xinc
        y+=yinc

point1 = [2,2]
point2 = [10,12] 

board[point1[0],point1[1]] = 2
board[point2[0],point2[1]] = 2

makeline()
printarr()
```

Explanation:

1. Find the distance to be covered in both the axes (dx and dy)
2. Compute the number of steps -> max no of cells to be covered in any axes
3. Find how much you need to increment
4. Loop for the number of steps and plot the point and increment. 
   You'll need to convert it to absolute value as list pointers need to be integers.

> ```
> 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
> 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
> 0 0 2 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
> 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
> 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
> 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0
> 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0
> 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
> 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
> 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0
> 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2
> 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
> 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
> ```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to cover all the squares that are touched by the line, you can implement the step size line method. I wrote a function that takes as input the matrix as mat, 2 points p1(x0,y0) and p2(x1,y1) which MUST be inside the matrix and have integer value(I did not check for these conditions in my example). The last value is the value you want your matrix to take.

```
    def draw_line(mat, x0, y0, x1, y1, value):
        step_number  = int(abs(x0-x1) + abs(y0-y1)) #Number of steps
        step_size = 1.0/step_number #Increment size
        p = [] #Point array (you can return this and not modify the matrix in the last 2 lines)
        t = 0.0 #Step current increment
        for i in range(step_number):
            p.append([x0 * t + x1 * (1 - t), y0 * t + y1 * (1 - t)])
            t+=step_size
        for i in range(len(p)):
            mat[int(round(p[i][0])), int(round(p[i][1]))] = block_value
```