# How to make a gradient line between two points in numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I hope to generate a gradient line between two points in a numpy array. For example, if I have a numpy array like

```
[[1,0,0,0]
 [0,0,0,0]
 [0,0,0,0]
 [0,0,0,4]]
```

What I hope to get is find a line between the `[0,0]` and `[3,3]`, and have a liner gradient. So I hope to make an array like

```
[[1,0,0,0]
 [0,2,0,0]
 [0,0,3,0]
 [0,0,0,4]]
```

The tricky part is the matrix may not be a perfect `nxn`. I don't care if some lines have two non-zero elements (because we cannot get a perfect diagonal for `mxn` matrix). The element of the same line can be the same in my case.

I am wondering is there an efficient way to make this happen?

Comment: maybe this will help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50387606/python-draw-line-between-two-coordinates-in-a-matrix

Answer (score 0):

You can use [np.fill_diagonal](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.fill_diagonal.html#numpy-fill-diagonal):

```
np.fill_diagonal(arr, np.arange(arr[0,0], arr[-1,-1]+1))
```

Output:

```
array([[1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 2, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 3, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 4]])
```

Comment: But this does not work with a mxn matrix. I think a line drawing algorithm is better.

Comment: well, give an example of what you want to happen with an mxn array

Comment: The np.fill_diagnoal will only work with top {nxn} for a {mxn} matrix (m > n). Or wrap the output. But I am looking for create a line between two points.